# Unattended PDF merge and print

Tags: pdf, automation, ghostscript, unattended, pdftk

My company is using an invoicing software that creates 3 ways invoice (original, duplicate and triplicate) as separate files which are sent to printer.
We need our printer to staple them automatically but in order to make it possible it should arrive as one single file to the printer.

If I point the invoicing software to an unattended pdf printer like PDFCreator I can get 3 files created for each way of the invoice naming those as I wish.

How can I manage to automatically merge them into a single file and than send to printer without any user intervention considering we can have peak times when 100+ invoices are created in a short time-frame?

Comment: Ghostscript is good for this. You could use a command similar to this: `gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile=3FilesCombined.pdf original.pdf duplicate.pdf triplicate.pdf` This will combine the last 3 filenames into one document called 3FIlesCombined.

Comment: From what I've been able to research, Ghostscript or pdftk is what I need to merge the files. In order for this to work properly I'd need to be able somehow to recursively have it combining each 3 latest files as soon as they're created, think this is the point I need help the most.

Comment: What do the filenames look like for the original/dupe/triplicate as of current? Can you provide a sample naming convention?

Comment: Considering I'll have to use something like PDFCreator in order to save the files as primary files, I'm free to define the naming as it fits best, was thinking using a simple counter so the first invoice would be 1/2/3.pdf, second 4/5/6 and so on.

Comment: @SkilledNoob Silly question, but why not tell the app in Print Options to print three consecutive copies with Collate Copies set on, when you select Print to PDF?

Comment: @K7AAY yeah, that would work but I have no such option, the invoicing software generates 3 separate print jobs, each for one way of invoice, that's why I need something to grab those 3 jobs and put them into one file so next I can use something like dropit to send it to printer automatically.

Comment: @SkilledNoob In testing, suggest you check the first three consecutive files against each other with _fc_ to make sure they actually do belong together, and to repeat with the next batch of three.. I'd want to make sure they actually do belong together. If they don't, then return to the idea of the invoicing app printing 3 copies to PDF, use _fc_ to look for matching files, and throw away the duplicates.

Comment: @K7AAY thanks for the tip!
I think I shouldn't need to employ fc here as all the ways of an invoice come in sequential order so when configuring something to merge those into one file, I'll have to point it to pick 3 files and probably right there I'll have to specify how does it pick the 3 files to merge.